# How to store ID of record in Firebase cloud functions

Tags: javascript, typescript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm saving data in the collection in the following way:

```
const userEntry= {
            UserId: "I want documentID here", 
            UserName: "",
            creationDate: ""
        }
const churchResult = await saveChurchData(userEntry)
const saveData = async (data: object) => {
    return database.collection('users').add(data)
        .then(snapshot => {
            return snapshot.get().then(doc => { 
                doc.data() 
                return doc.id
            }).catch(err => {
                console.log('Error getting documents', err);
                return null;
            });
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('Error getting documents', err);
            return null;
        });
}
```

Is there any way that I store "documentID" of users table in the place of `UserId`. How can we do that in firebase cloud functions? I'm unable to find a way to store the documentID in the documentation.

I tried following, but it is giving wrong ID not docuemntID:

```
    const key =firebase.database().ref().push()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I don't see any `saveChurchData()` method in your code, I make the assumption that instead of doing

```
const churchResult = await saveChurchData(userEntry)
```

you wan to do

```
const churchResult = await saveData(userEntry)
```

---

The following would do the trick, by using the [`doc()`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.CollectionReference#doc) method without specifying any `documentPath`:

```
const userEntry = {
    UserName: "",
    creationDate: ""
}

const churchResult = await saveData(userEntry)

const saveData = async (data: object) => {

    try {

        const docRef = database.collection('users').doc();
        const docId = docRef.id;

        await docRef.set({ UserId: docId, ...data });

        return docId;

    } catch (error) {
        //...
    }

}
```